# Datadog alarm based on multiple thresholds

Tags: alarm, datadog

I am struggling to see if this is at all possible. If I have 2 queries:
A: `avg:metric_one{service:foo}.as_count()`
B: `avg:metric_two{service:foo}.as_count()`
And a FUNC `(a/b)*100`
I'd like a simple alarm that triggers when:
`FUNC < 70 && A > 10`
However, there seems to not be any option to put 2 critiria in. Any advice?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this use case, create a [Composite Monitor](https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/create/types/composite/). With composites you can define your triggering conditions based on the combined status of multiple monitors.

Comment: that was quick, thank you kindly!